# Why MySQL dump command not working

Tags: cmd, mysql

I have got Windows10. I run cmd and then i go to my mysql location.

```
cd\
cd xampp\mysql\bin
```

Then i run mysql to check it.

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -u root -p
```

I get:

> Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g. Your MySQL
>   connection id is 49 Server version: 5.6.20 MySQL Community Server
>   (GPL)
>
> Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights
>   reserved.
>
> Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
>   affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.
>
> Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input
>   statement.
>
> mysql>

Then i type `exit` to back to the cmd. Until now there is no issues. Now i'm trying to make mysqldump:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysqldump -u root -p pswork > 'C:\backup\sql1.sql';
```

and i get:

> Nazwa pliku, nazwa katalogu lub składnia etykiety woluminu jest
>   niepoprawna.

for english translation

> The file name, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

I'm sure that my database is pswork and 'c:\backup\' directory is existing.
Why it's

Comment: remove the single qoutes around file and path

Comment: Just wondering: Is Windows having the POSIX output redirector >?

Comment: But now diff not working. `C:\xampp\mysql\bin>diff c:\backup\file1.sql c:\backup\file2.sql`. I get:
_'diff' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file_.

Comment: @frlan The Windows command shell interpreter was built on the MS-DOS command interpreter that [supported output redirection](http://www.os2museum.com/wp/dos/dos-2-0-and-2-1/) many years before the [POSIX standard emerged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#Name).

Comment: Good to know. Just not familar with windows to much ;)